# Linq with DynamicObject

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, dynamic

I have List where MyType : DynamicObject. The reason for MyType inheriting from DynamicObject, is that I need a type that can contain unknown number of properties.

It all works fine until I need to filter List. Is there a way I can do a linq that will do something like this:

```
return all items where any of the properties is empty string or white space?
```

Comment: There are other types that can contain unknown properties, such as `ExpandoObject`. Your life would be orders of magnitude easier if you could use `ExpandoObject` instead of `DynamicObject`.

Comment: I would need to check if UI controls that I am using support ExpandoObject, but if they do, I have no problem in making transition from DynamicObject to ExpandoObject. The question is, can I do above linq query with List<ExpandoObject>?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well as long as each object's properties are not *unknown internally* to themselves you could do it.

There isn't a great generic way to test all the properties of a dynamic object, if you don't have control over the `DynamicObject` you hope the implementer implemented `GetDynamicMemberNames()` and you can use the nuget package ImpromptuInterface's methods for [getting the property names](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/source/browse/ImpromptuInterface/src/Impromptu.cs#557) and [dynamically invoking those names](http://code.google.com/p/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageReallyLateBinding#dynamic_Impromptu.InvokeGet%28object_target,_String_Or_InvokeMembe).

```
return allItems.Where(x=> Impromptu.GetMemberNames(x, dynamicOnly:true)
                       .Any(y=>String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Impromptu.InvokeGet(x,y));
```

Otherwise, since it's your own type `MyType` you can add your own method that can see internal accounting for those member values.

```
return allItems.Where(x => x.MyValues.Any(y=>String.IsNullOrWhitespace(x));
```

Answer (score 3):

> (from the comment) can I do above linq query with List?

Yes, here is how you can do it with `ExpandoObject`:

```
var list = new List<ExpandoObject>();
dynamic e1 = new ExpandoObject();
e1.a = null;
e1.b = "";
dynamic e2 = new ExpandoObject();
e2.x = "xxx";
e2.y = 123;
list.Add(e1);
list.Add(e2);
var res = list.Where(
    item => item.Any(p => p.Value == null || (p.Value is string && string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)p.Value)))
);
```

The `ExpandoObject` presents an interface that lets you enumerate its property-value pairs as if they were in a dictionary, making the process of checking them a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to ExpandoObject. I am giving it +1, but cannot accept it as answer since I cannot inherit from ExpandoObject, and since jbtule has directly answered to my question.